# Why PHP redirect doesn't work when you pass the address of the page via GET?

Tags: php, redirect, header, get, http-status-code-302

Here's my code in redirect.php: (I know it's unpractical)

```
<?php
header("Location: " . $_GET['to']);
?>
```

And here's the problem. This page works and redirects correctly:

```
redirect.php?to=http://www.google.com
```

But this one doesn't:

```
redirect.php?to=http://www.google.com/
```

The problem is not with the final slash, this one doesn't work too:

```
redirect.php?to=http://www.google.com/intl/en/about/corporate/index.html
```

Neither does the urlencoded GET request:

```
redirect.php?to=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F
```

But the following erroneous ones do work: (Notice one slash in http:/)

```
redirect.php?to=http:/www.google.com/
redirect.php?to=http:/www.google.com/intl/en/about/corporate/index.html
```

And this one causes a 404 error on my own server as it should ("The requested url www.google.com not found on our server..."):

```
redirect.php?to=www.google.com/
```

On Firefox the erroneous ones show "The connection to the server was reset" and Chrome also shows the "Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): The connection was reset" page. Because of this I can't see what headers the server sends. Actually it seems it doesn't send any!

The funny part is that all of the above requests work fine when i test them on my localhost with WampServer, but when I upload them, it just doesn't work! There is no output or BOM before header, no proxy is used and all work is done on port 80. Can be my server config (which config?) the source of the problem?

I can't think of anything else to try and experiment.

I've already read some issues with redirecting after sending POST data but I don't think it's related to this problem.

**EDIT:**

Tried sending 301 / 303 status headers before the Location header... No Luck.
Called a friend and asked him to test with his different PC and different ISP... No Luck.
Wrote another script in ASCII encoding (instead of utf8)... No luck.

Please point me to other tests and diagnosis I can make on the issue.

Comment: does it work if you try `redirect.php?to=www.google.com/` and have your header set to `header("Location: http://" . $_GET['to']);` ?

Comment: You give the parameters being passed into redirect.php, but it might be better to give the headers it generates instead. Look into those with the dev tools.

Comment: @positiv: This does work, but there are lots of references to redirect.php and a quite large database of redirect-able links are already in my db which i don't want to change.

Comment: @Jon: Could you give more info?

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel: Actually no. I incorrectly thought that he was trying to pass in characters from the `unsafe` group as defined in [RFC 1945](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1945#section-3.2.1), which is indeed a problem.

Comment: `rawurlencoding` didn't work. It converted `http://` to `http%3A%2F%2F` and caused a 404 error to be shown by my server.

Answer (score 2):

> this one doesn't: redirect.php?to=http://www.google.com/

Negative.

> Neither does the urlencoded GET request: redirect.php?to=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F

Negative.

Both works.
You have to debug your code to find what's the problem.

- Instead of doing a redirect and guessing of the results, **do print your received value onto screen and examine it**
- instead of watching bogus browser errors you have to watch **actual HTTP headers** sent to the browser.

I suppose it's some code in redirect.php spoiling your data. Something like silly "making all data safe at once" routine.

Comment: As I explained, since Chrome and Firefox showed their `Connection Reset` error page, Both DevTools and FireBug failed to show me any headers. Please show me some tool capable of showing headers of pages who fail to load?

Comment: @Col.Sharpnel: Ah, also as I told you, it works PERFECTLY on my local computer using WAMP, the problem appears when I really upload it to the server. Is there some kind of server configuration which controls the beaviour of such things?

Comment: does it reset if you don't redirect but merely print the value out?

Comment: In chrome devtools, open the network tab before accessing the redirect.php script. It can show you the actual headers being sent and received.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel: No. `<?php $r = "Location: " . $_GET['to']; echo $r; header($r); ?>` prints out the correct output: `Location: http://www.google.com/ Warning: headers already sent...`

Comment: @Eli: I just thought it works but it doesn't :( DevTools shows the headers and resources of Chrome's error page instead of my page. I don't think pages send any headers when we encounter a reset connection.

Answer (score 0):

Why not pass it as `urlencode(base64_encode($url))`, then redirect as `base64_decode(urldecode($url))`.

It doesnt solve the issue, but I'd be interested to se whether this works (it may help to identify the underlying problem).

Comment: Base 64 encoding does work. Doing `header("Location: http://" . $_GET['to']  . '/');` also works, but I'm not interested in that way.

Comment: I'm not going to use base64 in the final implementation. @ErgoSummary: Someone downvoted every post in this question :S

Answer (score 0):

Can't you implement something like this...

Go to URL http://website.com/redirect.php?to=google.com

and then add the bits that you want to the URL within your PHP code, like so:

```
<?php
header("Location: http://" . $_GET['to']  . '/');
?>
```

You might try encoding the URL and then decoding it in your script to prevent anomalies

```
echo '<a href="redirect.php?to=' , urlencode("http://www.google.com/") , '">Click Here</a>';
```

and then decode it for the redirect

```
<?php
header("Location: " . urldecode($_GET['to']) );
?>
```

Comment: Some of my links might be ftp, smtp, whatever. And my site is full of links to redirect.php, I don't want to change every case. I'm looking for a more general way. And no, `urlencode` didn't help (as you already saw in the examples.) By the way, didn't you know `urldecode` should not be used on $_GET items?

Comment: Both solutions makes no sense while original The OP's approach is all right. Extremely deceiving answer.

Comment: I agree, deceiving answer, thanks to Luke Coulton; but had already tried it with no luck.

Comment: A bit late but, "*`urldecode` should not be used on $_GET items*" would rather be "*`urldecode` **does not need to** be used on $_GET items*". There are rare cases which it actually corrupts GET data however. Like the cases which user wants to send a %-encoded character or string literally.

Comment: @Hossein Unhelpful - probably.  Or just not what you're looking for?  That's the phrase you meant to say!  There seems to be a little confusion about the meaning of 'deceiving' here. Some answers that are not correct, but may serve as a spark for other ideas to form thus aiding a solution.

Comment: @LukeCoulton: To tell you the truth, I didn't look up deceive in the dictionary and now I do (MW Collegiate, meaning 2b: To fail to fulfill) I see it means the opposite of the way I used it here. Thanks Goodness that doesn't affect my TOEFL degree status. Thanks for your answer. It might be helpful to others but I had already considered it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try looking for any printed characters outside the php tags? This would silently break your redirect.

Try leaving the php tag open,. this would solve white space problems after php's closing tag. Something like this

```
<?php
header("Location: " . $_GET['to']);
// no closing tag and no content after
```

Other than that, is this code included by another piece of code that might have printed something on the html before the header call?

Comment: I was careful about spaces, new lines, BOM characters, whatever. The file is neither included nor includes.

Answer (score 0):

You should never use raw inputs to send headers as it makes your application vulnerable to [response splitting attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_response_splitting).

You can find some good examples on the [SecuriTeam website](http://www.securiteam.com/securityreviews/5WP0E2KFGK.html).

Comment: This is just a minimal example. In real implementation first the address is checked to make sure it exists in a hardcoded array of valid links. Thanks for the useful link.